# For /F Combined with Findstr to store a specific Text in File to a Variable

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, findstr

So I have a file named as Userdetails.dll
It contains  the following content.

ABC XYZ

DEF ZYX

GHI YXZ

Let's say the strings on the left side of each line are the names of users and the ones on the right are passwords.

Now, how do I create a batch file wherein the User is allowed to input his User name. The script then checks if the user name is valid from the list. If it is valid, it allows the user to input the password, if not then it exits. If the password inputted by the user matches with that mentioned in the .txt file, then it prints "Logged in" (ie Echo Logged in). If not it echoes "Invalid Password" and loops the user to Entering the Password Stage.

I have tried searching the the forum for this, but I did not find any   direct link. However all of the links led me to the use of For /f and Findstr in my code.
I need to know how to use for /f and findstr to provide the desired result.
 for /f %%A in ('findstr "User" userdetails.txt') d
o set usrname=%%A

However it returns the username and not the relevant password of the user.
Hence I would like to know how to use the command to return password from the username inputted by searching it in the file.
**Note. I am not a programmer(by profession). Hence I request you to explain me the code you have written line by line. Thanks a lot.**

Comment: If you are not a programmer you are wrong here! This is a site for asking and answering programming-related questions. You seem to confuse it with a free code writing service. Please learn [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) here! To make this post [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), you need to share your efforts, describe clearly what your attempt is intended to do and what it actually does...

Comment: @aschipfl
Okay. I guess, I was not specific, when I said I was not a programmer I meant by profession. However, I have written some basic codes, and am aware of the same. I began with my code, on user input.
After this, I proceeded with entering this in my code 
for /f %%A in ('findstr "Whatever the name user inputs" userdetails.txt') do set usrname=%%A
This is where I got stuck up, As the variable usrname would only return with the username and not password.
So I wanted some help as to how I could get to the password.
Hope this helps.

Comment: @aschipfl I have already done that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer out of mercy. Don't ask people to just write code for you, good way to get flagged.

```dos
@rem Hide the commands being submitted, standard to make things not look ugly.
@echo off
rem Completely optional and useless color change.
color f0
rem Use delayed expansion for 'safer' variable handling.
rem Delayed expansion means, variables are translated to their values as they are needed, rather than having a set in stone value.
rem This means special symbols will be treated as strings instead of as a command, and a variable in a block of code can have it's value changed and read in the same block.
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

rem Set path to the file that holds the usernames and password.
set "dataFile=C:\Users\Aresc\Desktop\userPass.txt"

:main
rem Call username method.
call :requestUsername
rem Call password method.
call :requestPassword
rem Pause,
pause
rem Then close.
exit

:requestUsername
rem Wipe the screen
cls

rem Wipe variables.
set "strUsername="
set "strCurrentUserPass="

rem Prompt for username via user input, storing into strUsername.
set /p "strUsername=Input Username:"

rem If the username is blank aka they just pressed {enter}, ask again.
if "!strUsername!" equ "" goto :requestUsername

rem Loop our datafile, line by line, grabbing the first and second word,
rem the first word is stored temp as %%G, second temp as %%H.
for /f "tokens=1,2" %%G in (!dataFile!) do (
    rem Check if the first word [username in dataFile] matches input username.
    if "!strUsername!" equ "%%G" (
        rem If it does, store the second word [the password in out dataFile] as a variable for later.
        set "strCurrentUserPass=%%H"
        rem Return to the call in ':main'.
        rem Note, a 'goto :eof' tells cmd to return to the last 'call' command location.
        rem In this case, the last call was from ':main', when i ran 'call :requestUsername'
        goto :eof
    )
)
rem If that above `for /f` loop found no matches with the `if` check, the input username wasnt valid.
exit

:requestPassword
rem Wipe variables
set "strPassword="

rem Prompt for password via user input, storing into strPassword.
set /p "strPassword=Input Password for user '!strUsername!':"

rem If the username is blank aka they just pressed {enter}, ask again.
if "!strUsername!" equ "" goto :requestPassword

rem Check if the user input matches the variable we stored from the `for /f` and `if` check.
if "!strPassword!" equ "!strCurrentUserPass!" (
    rem If it did match, do stuff, in this case echo to the screen,
    echo Logged in.
    rem then return to the call in `:main`.
    goto :eof
) else (
    rem If it did not match, tell them
    echo Invalid Password.
    rem Write a blank line, useless but it's an attempt to make a batch menu look organized.
    echo:
    rem Ask them again.
    goto :requestPassword
)
rem If there is some error with the `if` check above, exit. [Good habit.]
exit
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks a lot for taking so much efforts. Tried upvoting you but apparently,for a member who has less than 15 points, his votes do not get publicly counted.And as edited previously, I was not asking for the entire piece of code, but just that part wherein I was stuck at For /f and findstr. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Again. Your code works perfectly. I had some questions here.

Comment: 1. Why did you use Delayed Expansion variables instead of Percent Expansion ones.

Comment: 2. From your code, I did not understand the for /f part. How does the code understand on which line username was located, I could see that you have added the if equal to condition, but how does it proceed further (which it does) if the username was not on the first line itself. ie. How does the code determine to go to the next line if the Username was not found on the first line and so on. Also what does goto :eof do here ?
Thanks again for helping.

Comment: Delayed expansion tends to be easier to handle 'rogue' characters, if this was not enabled the program would misbehave when you type `&, *, |, ^, <>` etc. And `for /f` is a loop, the "`tokens=1,2` means pick the first and second word, no need for a delimiter, as it's `" "` (space) by default. So i just grab the first word into `%%G`, and the second word gets put into the next letter, `%%H`

Comment: Negate that, i'll just add some explaining in the answer.

Comment: Thanks again.
Also how would you approach if the in the userdetails.txt, the user name was stored on the first line and password on the second line.

Comment: I mean how would you edit the for /f code to make sure as soon as a match for username is found, the computer looks on the next line to check if the password is correct or not. Basically, how do you add the option to check next line.

Comment: In your question, you say to ask for a username, validate, then ask for a password. This could only be done if the username was not validated.
Then the if statement in the for /f loop could be `if "%%G" equ "!strUsername!" (if "%%H" equ "!strPassword!" (rem Input code on correct credentials))`, and if the password and username were inverted locations, just switch `%%G` and `%%H` in the if statements.

Answer (score 0):

By default `for /f` tokenizes the input lines using spaces and tabs as delimiters, and only reads the first token in the line.

As your input lines contain a space, only the first element in the line is retrieved. You need to disable delimiters to retrieve the full line inside the `for` replaceable parameter

```dos
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('
    findstr /l /c:"%whatever%" userdetails.txt
`) do set "userdetails=%%a"
```

or you can indicate that you want to retrieve the two first tokens in the line, each of them stored in a separate `for` replaceable parameter

```dos
for /f "tokens=1,2" %%a in ('
    findstr /l /c:"%whatever%" userdetails.txt
`) do (
    set "username=%%a"
    set "password=%%b"
)
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks a lot for taking so much efforts. Tried upvoting you but apparently,for a member who has less than 15 points, his votes do not get publicly counted. However when I tried to input it and run the batch file, it does not seem to work. So I tried to echo the username and password, both appear to be blank. Could you help ?

Comment: @x0nar, obviously the code asumes a valid input from the user. Have you tested the contents of the input variable? Have you tried with `findstr /i` to use case insensitive search? Are you trying to `echo` the data from inside the `for` loop using the variables without delayed expansion?

Comment: My Apologies ! Apparently I mistakenly pressed enter while copying the bracket part. This is to inform you that your code works perfectly fine. And I thank you for helping me.

Comment: Just to make sure I understood it, let me confirm the same with you. 
So the findstr part searches for the username inputted by the user, and as soon as a match is found it records the line. After doing that it goes to the line recorded and stores the first string in %%A, second in %%B and so on. Just let me know if my understanding was right.

Comment: Also how would you reframe the code if the txt file contained details in the following manner
User : ABC
Password : XYZ

Comment: @x0nar, more or less, `findstr` extracts all lines that match the search condition, and the `for` loop will iterate over all the selected lines. As two tokens are requested and the first is `%%a` the second will be `%%b`. For the last case, you will need `for /f "tokens=2,4 delims=: " %%a in .... do echo %%a %%b` splitting the line using the colons and spaces as delimiters and retrieving two tokens (`%%a`, `%%b`) that are the second and fourth, tokens in the line

Comment: Thanks again. I now understand this part. However in my last query I meant if the data is stored as following. <br/> User : ABC <br/> Password :  XYZ <br/> User : DEF <br/> Password : LMNO. (i.e there is a line between User and Password for each usernames). In this case how would you address for /f to search for the password in the next line for the corresponding user. Really Appreciate your help.

Comment: @x0nar, comments are very limited. Please, start a new question.

Comment: Apparently, I am blocked from asking a question due to the "Question being not well received from the community". So it seems that I'll have to wait a day. Could you be able to answer the question tomorrow, after I am eligible to post it. Thanks.